# std::string::erase doesn't work as I expected

Tags: c++, c++11

There are many questions here on splitting string by comma. I am trying to make another one.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include<cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "1.11,       2.11,       3.11,       4.11,       5.11,    ";
    str1.erase(std::remove_if(str1.begin(), str1.end(), [](unsigned char x){return std::isspace(x);}));
    std::cout<<"New string = "<<str1<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting the unexpected output below.

`New string = 1.11,2.11,3.11,4.11,5.11,          4.11,           5.11,`

Did I miss something?

Comment: Why are you removing spaces if you want to split by comma?

Comment: " I am trying to make another one." hm? you are trying to make a question about splitting a string by comma? your question rather looks like one about removing spaces....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::remove_if` moves the non-removed elements to the front of the string, and returns iterator to the first element to be erased.  You use the single iterator argument `erase`, which only erases a single element. To erase all of the matching characters, you need to use the two argument version, by passing `end` iterator:

```
str1.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        str1.begin(),
        str1.end(),
        [](unsigned char x){return std::isspace(x);}
    ),
    str1.end() // this was missing
);
```

---

In case you were wondering why there are some non-space characters at the end, `std::remove_if` is not required the keep the *eliminated* elements intact, and some of them have been overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

There are two iterator based versions of `string::erase`. One that erases a single character, and one that erases a range. You have to add the end of the range to get rid of all of it.

```
str1.erase(std::remove_if(str1.begin(), str1.end(),
                          [](unsigned char x){return std::isspace(x);}),
           str1.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `erase` uses the single iterator argument overload, which removes 1 character. Add `str1.end()` as second argument to get the usual remove+erase idiom.